# Autogenerate function header, variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have a problem, I defined a template class to cope with systems of different dimensions as a follow:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class system {

    std::array<cv::Mat, N> matrices;

    ...

};
```

then I need to define different function that takes different parameters based on the size of the system. Something like that:

```
template <>
template<typename T>
void system<1>::fun(T & a){ }

template <>
template<typename T>
void system<2>::fun(T & a, T & b){ }

template <>
template<typename T>
void system<3>::fun(T & a, T & b, T & c){ }
```

However tried to uses this strategy the compiler gives the following error:

```
Out-of-line definition of 'fun' does not match any declaration in 'system<3>'
```

Moreover I would like that the headers functions will be autogenerate based on the template parameter `N`. I tried to use variadic template but without fortune.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but this approach seems wrong IMO. You'd probably have better luck using something else to auto-generate code (e.g.: a small script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can auto generate based on N, I guess that you can write the code to do what you need generically (your comment that you tried to use variadics reinforces that).

The fact that your function is also templated on `T` unfortunately complicates things a little more than I would like. There are simpler solutions than what I will give, but the only ones I saw require you to either specify the type explicitly, or defer checking to runtime that could be done at compile time. As it stands, the only way I can see to do what you want is to use variadic templates.  This gets most of what you want:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class System {

   template <class ... Ts>
   void fun(Ts& ts) {
       static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == N, "Wrong number of parameters!");       
    }
};
```

I've static asserted rather than enable if, to keep things simpler (and it since it's highly unlikely it will make a difference unless you plan to have another member function named `fun`... don't do that). Now, this function will only accept being called with N arguments, but it will allow all the types to vary. You want them all to be the same. So we need a bit of TMP.

```
template <class ... Ts>
struct all_same{};

template <class T>
struct all_same<T> : std::true_type {
    using same_type = T;    
};

template <class T, class ... Ts>
struct all_same<T, T, Ts...> : all_same<T, Ts...> {};

template <class T1, class T2, class ... Ts>
struct all_same<T1, T2, Ts...> : std::false_type {};
```

Some classic recursive TMP gets us what we want. Both a true false indicator of whether all the types in the pack are the same, and if they are the same we can access the common type. Once we have a common type, and have verified the size, we can use the pack to initialize an array and loop over it, so we don't have to keep doing annoying variadic style programming inside our function:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct System {

   template <class ... Ts>
   void fun(Ts&... ts) {
       static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == N, "Wrong number of parameters!");
       using same = all_same<Ts...>;
       static_assert(same::value, "All types must be the same!");
       std::array<std::reference_wrapper<typename same::same_type>, N> x{ts...};
       for (auto& e : x) { std::cerr << e << std::endl; }
    }
};
```

Modifying this solution to suit your exact needs will require a bit of expertise in C++, and also you'll need to watch our for certain tricky situations, e.g. when you pass both string literals and `std::string`s or other types that you are used to being implicitly convertible, it will fail. Still, hope this helps get you going. Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08ac23da33deb8ef.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. My first attempt with the variadic templates was a mess. However, I have some trouble with std::reference_wrapper with more complex template type. In any case thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could also make `foo` more generic using `integer_sequence` and alias template. (`integer_sequence` is c++14 but there exist c++11 implementations as well):

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <class T, std::size_t>
using typer = T;

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct S;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct S<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>{

    std::array<int, N> matrices;

    template <class T>
    void foo(typer<const T&, Is>... args) {
        int dummy[] = { ((matrices[Is] = args), void(), 0)... };
        static_cast<void>(dummy);
    }
};

int main() {
    S<3> s;
    s.foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XrhPseMSmBnTMfGY)

Comment: This is definitely nicer than my solution, exploiting the fact that N is known and doesn't need to be deduced.

Comment: @NirFriedman well on the other hand it does need a constexpr indexing background/experiance and may not be as obvious at first glance...

Comment: Yes more elegant though. IMHO it is in the vein of "obvious once you have already seen it". Though, I did not really see a very nice way to apply it to free functions. It seems like you have to forward to an implementation function but that is rather disadvantageous as it does not sfinae properly.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be define the function inside the body of the class (en passant: avoid the name `system()`: can collide with the standard function), using SFINAE, as follows

```
template <std::size_t N>
class systemClass
 {
   private: 
      std::array<FooType, N> matrices;

   public:
      template<typename T, std::size_t M = N>
      typename std::enable_if<M == 1U>::type fun(T & a) { }

      template<typename T, std::size_t M = N>
      typename std::enable_if<M == 2U>::type fun(T & a, T & b) { }

      template<typename T, std::size_t M = N>
      typename std::enable_if<M == 3U>::type fun(T & a, T & b, T & c) { }
 };
```

> Moreover I would like that the headers functions will be autogenerate based on the template parameter N. I tried to use variadic template but without fortune.

I'm agree with UnholySheep: isn't clear to me what do you exactly want but I suspect that a solution could be a shell script to generate the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know my question was not so clear. I also think that a shell script  may be the solution. Anyhow I also like your solution but in order to avoid to specify the different fun() functions the @nir solution works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your function variadic, but only accepting the right number of parameter. It would look like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct system {
    template<typename... Ts>
    auto fun(Ts&&... ts) -> std::enable_if_t<(N == sizeof...(Ts))> {
        // function content
    }

private:
    std::array<cv::Mat, N> matrices;
};
```

The enable if will only allow the function to exist if the number of parameters is equal to `N`.